# Knockout Dropdown Values Not Changing When ObservableArray Changed

Tags: knockout.js

I have a  element bound to an observable array, however when a value in the observable array changes, the drop down does not change. What am I doing wrong? I want to be able to select an observable object, change one of its values and have the drop down reflect the changes. In the jsfiddle, just select a value in the drop down, change the text, and click update.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qt6Lmtrr/)

Javascript:

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    self.programs = ko.observableArray([
        {programId: 1, programDescription: 'One'},
        {programId: 2, programDescription: 'Two'},
        {programId: 3, programDescription: 'Three'}
    ]);
    self.program = ko.observable();

    self.saveProgram = function () {

        for (i = 0; i < self.programs().length - 1 ; i++) {
            if (self.programs()[i].programId == self.program().programId) {
                self.programs()[i].programDescription =
                    self.program().programDescription;
                alert(self.programs()[i].programDescription);
            }
        } 

    };

};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

html:

```
<div>
    <select data-bind="options: programs,
                       optionsText: 'programDescription',
                       value: program"></select>
</div>
<div>
    Update Program Description: <input type="text" data-bind="value: program().programDescription" />
    <button type="button" data-bind="click: saveProgram">Update</button>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`programDescription`s need to be observables so the view is updated when the value is changed...

```
self.programs = ko.observableArray([
    {programId: 1, programDescription: ko.observable('One')},
    {programId: 2, programDescription: ko.observable('Two')},
    {programId: 3, programDescription: ko.observable('Three')}
]);
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/90ncjsbw/)

Answer (score 0):

If you simply make the field observable you'll be changing the field directly (it will update in the select) which will allow you to get rid of the `save` function and the `Update` button.

Then the question of whether you want the ability to `cancel` the edit is raised in which I would recommend consulting [Simple Editor pattern](http://www.knockmeout.net/2013/01/simple-editor-pattern-knockout-js.html).

```js
var Item = function (args) {
  return {
    programId: args.programId,
    programDescription: ko.observable(args.programDescription)
  }
}

var ViewModel = function () {
var self = this;
self.programs = ko.observableArray([
new Item({programId: 1, programDescription: 'One'}),
new Item({programId: 2, programDescription: 'Two'}),
new Item({programId: 3, programDescription: 'Three'})]);
self.program = ko.observable();
self.editContainer = ko.observable();
self.program.subscribe(function (nv) {
    self.editContainer(ko.toJS(nv))
})
self.cancel = function () {
    self.editContainer(null);
    self.program(null)
}
self.update= function () {
    self.program().programDescription(self.editContainer().programDescription)
    self.program(null)
};
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div>
<select data-bind="options: programs,
                   optionsText: 'programDescription',
                   optionsCaption: 'Choose...',
                  value: program"></select>
</div>
<div data-bind='with: editContainer'>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Editor</legend>Program Description:
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: programDescription" />
    <br/>
    <button type="button" data-bind="click: $root.update">Update</button>
    <button type="button" data-bind="click: $root.cancel">Cancel</button>
</fieldset>
</div>
```